# add some extra days to active users subscription in google play console

Tags: subscription, google-play-console

I want to add 15 days to all my active subscription users for free.

for example if a user expiration date is 1 April, I want to change it to 15 April by API or from Google Play Console.

is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, if you already integrated in-app promotions in your app.

> You can create promotion codes to give selected users an extended free trial to an existing subscription SKU.

Check out the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/promo) to know how to apply.

Comment: Have you tried that? Seems it is not possible to extend an active subscription with promo codes. It is applicable only for a new subscription. The only way i have found is through deferring a billing period 
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subscriptions#defer

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this functionality by using https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subscriptions#defer from the server side, assuming you store and know the information about active subscriptions